# How to convert Javascript string of array to array?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have a data-type element for each option in select box. When I select an option I get the data-type as `"[{:type=>"textbox", :label=>"Age"}]"` (string of array of hashes). I want to convert this to array of hashes. I searched in google but couldn't get any. Can anyone help.

I tried replace as well,
 `str.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"' , ']');` but didnt get result. I want this in Javascript.

Comment: but that is not coming in JSON format. SO am not able to acheive that.

Comment: Is that what the value actually looks like? What kind of syntax is that? It's not JSON and it doesn't look like PHP either. Sounds to me like you need a bonafide parser, and that may be outside the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for this one sample anyway:

```
var a = '[{:type=>"textbox", :label=>"Age"}]';

var b = JSON.parse(a.replace(/:/g, '"').replace(/=>/g,'":'));

console.table(b);
```

Comment: what if I get string as "[{:type=>"textbox", :label=>"Age"}]"; ? because javascript is giving me string in the above way